# Как работают сервисы для совместного просмотра видео?

Tags: веб-программирование

Как работают сервисы для совместного просмотра видео?
Например, этот [сайт](https://app.kosmi.io/room/pz4ee3) позволяет выбрать видео на ютубе и смотреть одновременно нескольким пользователям, которые находятся в комнате. Также там есть pluto.tv (тв обычное), которое можно смотреть в эфире прям.

Как это все технически устроено? Я что-то совсем не представляю, как работает потоковое вещание live-видео, да и обычного видео с ютуба, ведь доступа к контенту нет